# Spring boot and Thymeleaf - Hot swap templates and resources once again

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, hotswap

I tried all tips and tricks that I found here and in docs, but still no luck. I have Spring webapp with Thymeleaf. Resources and templates are not reloaded when I call update in IDEA (it says nothing to reload). I can then press ctrl+f5 in a browser like crazy, changes are just not there.

Everything is configured in one Java class like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
```

My folder structure now looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFKWb.png), but I also tried to put the resources without "static" folder or to webapp/resources.

ResourceHandlerRegistry:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/img/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
}
```

I specified cache=false in both application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

and in mentioned MvcConfig class:

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

According to some answers on SO i added dependency for devtools:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Still not working. Some said to add maven boot plugin with addResources=true, so I did:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My Idea is set properly I guess, because when I call update, my Java classes are reloaded immediately. Only resources and html files are not, I must restart server for it. Actualy *.html files are not so big a deal, but to restart server after every small css and js change is slowing me down a lot, and as I lost almost 15 hours figuring out what is wrong, it started to be really frustrating.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What I just found out is that changes are actualy reflected in "target" folder, but not in the running app itself.

Comment: this one did the trick for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399586/hot-swapping-in-spring-boot/43114954#43114954

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have spent some time on it and finally here I'll explain how I got it working.
Googling around you may find several info:

- [Spring Boot hot swap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)
- [SO - Spring Boot + Jetty & hot deployment](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html)
- [SO - Netbeans 8 won't reload static Thymeleaf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103860/netbeans-8-wont-reload-static-thymeleaf-files)

My inital approach was to disable caching and add Spring dev tools:

Spring boot `application.properties`

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/templates/
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Using the snippet above however is not enough since the hot swap is done only when making the project (CTRL + F9 in Intellij Idea). This is due to the fact that **the default template resolver is classpath based** and that's the reason a recompilation is necessary.

---

**A working solution** is to override the `defaultTemplateResolver` by using a file system based resolver:

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.templates_root=src/main/resources/templates/
```

Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    @Autowired
    private ThymeleafProperties properties;

    @Value("${spring.thymeleaf.templates_root:}")
    private String templatesRoot;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        FileTemplateResolver resolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setSuffix(properties.getSuffix());
        resolver.setPrefix(templatesRoot);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(properties.getMode());
        resolver.setCacheable(properties.isCache());
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I find this solution optimal since it allow you to externalize the configuration and use different profiles (dev, prod, etc..) while having the benefit of reloading the changes by **just pressing F5 :)**

Comment: I get a warning `Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.thymeleaf.templates_root'`. Does this property really exist?

Comment: it exist if you write it, see the example `application.properties` in the answer

Comment: use one line config can do last work(override defaultTemplateResolver): spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:///${user.dir}/src/main/resources/templates/

Comment: As @JianrongChen says -- simpler still to just set `spring.thymeleaf.prefix`. I've posted this as an answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72928208/768795

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to configure Spring's Thymeleaf template source to load from the filesystem, rather than the classpath.

This is a super-simple -- esentially a one-liner in config -- but seems little-known on the Internet. Credit to @JianrongChen's for posting it in his comment.

**application.properties**

```
# Thymeleaf templates from filesystem, not cached
#
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/

# static content from filesystem first, too
#
spring.web.resources.static-locations[0]=file:src/main/resources/static/
spring.web.resources.static-locations[1]=classpath:/static
```

References:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.templating.spring.thymeleaf.prefix

Answer (score 3):

Here are my settings with IntelliJ IDEA (2018.3), it's reload HTML after the changes are saved:

1. In application.properties:

   ```
   spring.resources.static-locations = classpath:/resources/static
   spring.resources.cache.period = 0
   ```
2. In pom.xml, set `<addResources>true</addResources>`

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <addResources>true</addResources>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Menu `Run` => `Edit Configurations` (IntelliJ IDEA)

On frame deactivation: `Update resources`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found answer to my specific case. Problem was not at all in my app or it's config (well.. probably). Instead of using **Tomcat 8.5.5** I switched back to **Tomcat 7**. Everything now works properly. Does somebody know why?

Answer (score 0):

@Luke my solution was quite simple:

To have HTML / CSS / JS reloading automatically in Spring Thymeleaf can be simple and bug free, have only tested in IntelliJ.

Add this to maven, use ${spring.version} var or replace by your version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Add to the header of the html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

When using IntelliJ:

[image: using Ctrl+Shift+A write Registry]

[image: In IntelliJ Settings]